# Can I navigate a web browser (e.g. chromium) with my keyboard, based on elements' positions rather than their tab index?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

Sometimes I want to navigate my web browser (mainly chrome) without a mouse.

For the most part this is easy, Ctrl+K to search, Ctrl+T for a tab, etc.

Navigating webpages themselves sequentially based on element's `tabindex` with Tab and Shift+Tab is a pain, though. Are there key shortcuts (or possibly extensions) that I'm missing that would let me navigate a webpage based on an element's position on the screen, rather than it's `tabindex`?

A use case would be, for example, navigating the question list of https://superuser.com/. Tabbing through works, but you need to cycle through each tag, the user profile link, and the time modified for every question before highlighting the next question link.

Comment: That would be a horrible user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried F7 to toggle on caret browsing if your browser supports it?

This functionality should help your use-case: You could arrow down to move the cursor through the location of the questions, and then use tab to focus on the question link, without ever selecting the other elements (profiles etc.).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).